# Error on checking out Chrome V8 Wiki from Git Hub

Tags: github, v8, git-checkout, windows-server-2016

I am using Tortoise SVN v1.9.5 to checkout Google Chrome V8 Wiki (trunk) content in my Windows Server 2016 machine from GitHub link of `https://github.com/v8/v8.wiki.git` and I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with  
Error:  'D:\ChromeV8\wiki\trunk\images', work item 44 (file-install  
Error:  trunk/What-should-I-do-if-my-CL-broke-the-Node.js-integration-build?.md 1 0 1  
Error:  1)  
Error: Can't move 'D:\ChromeV8\wiki\.svn\tmp\svn-B67F3A8B' to  
Error:  'D:\ChromeV8\wiki\trunk\What-should-I-do-if-my-CL-broke-the-Node.js-integration-build?.md':  
Error:  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Any help to fix this issue or understand the cause of this error will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Windows doesn't support `?` occurring in file names. Why do you want to clone the wiki? Can you use a non-Windows OS (e.g. a Linux virtual machine)?

Comment: If `?` is the problem, then I may need to use a non-Windows machine to clone it. I just thought of getting the wiki easily offline and that is why I cloned it. Is there way to clone by only skipping the file causing trouble during checkout?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what tricks TortoiseSVN is capable of (I didn't even know it supported cloning git repositories). In theory, cloning the repository and checking out a revision to your working directory are distinct steps.
Another idea for offline access would be using `wget` to create a mirror of the website.

Comment: I just cloned it using a virtual machine running Ubuntu and it works perfectly fine there. So, I am marking yours as the answer. Hope V8 will address this and get this fixed, as these code lines are something which is supposed to be worked on from any OS platform seamlessly.